# Горлышко - горловина... Какой предлог, если в нём/ней что-то виднеется?

Tags: выбор-слов, предлоги, стилистическая-сочетаемость

> Наш Ямамото ценит стиль, качество и предпочитает просторные одежды
>   чёрного или глубокого тёмно-синего цвета. Быть может, **в горлышке**
>   иногда мелькнёт белая футболка. Поскольку он небольшого росточка, а
>   прикид – хорошее итальянское кашемировое пальто или болоньевый плащ и
>   дорогие ботинки, всегда с чужого и сытого плеча, то на маленьком
>   вертлявом человечке с каким-то редким внутренним чувством стиля
>   смотрится такой наряд отрадно.

Вестимо, хочу переделать горлышко на горловину, а на предлоге запнулась... Может, и горлышко на месте?

Ничего, что ботинки - с плеча? Как быть-то?

А если я внутреннее чувство стиля заменю на нутряное, я очень подведу месседж?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Идею я не очень уловила (мне кажется, что грамматика неясная) и пока что просто переписала отрывок под свое понимание (поэтому за правильность содержания не ручаюсь, а форма выбрана под это содержание).

Наш Ямамото ценит стиль, качество и предпочитает просторные одежды чёрного или глубокого тёмно-синего цвета (быть может, только иногда **в вороте** мелькнёт белая футболка). Росточка он небольшого, а прикид всегда с чужого и сытого плеча — хорошее итальянское кашемировое пальто, болоньевый плащ, дорогие ботинки.  Но — странное дело! —  на маленьком вертлявом человечке с его особенным чувством гармонии и вкуса   смотрится такой  наряд весьма отрадно.

2) **Пояснение формы "в вороте"**

*Горлышко* и *горловина* не подходят (горловина — это скорее терминологическое выражение, не для художественного текста).

А ***ворот*** — это **вырез в одежде**, поэтому в вороте может быть видна футболка.

ГОРЛЫШКО, ср. 1. Уменьш.-ласк.  к Горло (1 зн.). Не хочешь промочить г. (выпить чего-л.). 2.  Верхняя суженная часть сосуда. Г. бутылки.

ГОРЛОВИНА 4. Вырез **у платья**, кофты, к которому пришивают воротник.

ВОРОТ,  м. Вырез **в одежде для шеи**; пришитая к этому вырезу и облегающая шею полоса ткани. Платье с воротом. Расстегнуть в. Открытый в. (не закрывающий шею).

Я смутно помнил невысокого человека в синенькой рубашке **с металлической цепочкой в вороте на шее**, но как он выглядел конкретно, забыл совершенно. [Марк Зайчик. В нашем регионе // «Звезда», 2002]